# How to get multiple lines from a .txt file that have been split and to save them into different variables

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def WorkLoad():
readWork=open("Todays_Work.txt","r")
for line in readWork.readlines(): 
    WorkLine = line.split()
    Order_No = WorkLine[0]
    Deliver_Address = WorkLine[1]
    Bay_Collection = WorkLine[2]
    Stock = WorkLine[3]
print(WorkLine[0],"\n",WorkLine[1],"\n",WorkLine[2],"\n",WorkLine[3])
print(WorkLine)
```

I am currently started of with this but it only prints out the last line in the text file.

Comment: Are you sure this is all of your code? Apart from the indentation there isn't anything particularly wrong with it. Are you printing all those variables?

Comment: You probably need to use a `list` and append data to it.  You are currently overwriting data in each iteration.

Comment: If you want to execute the function WorkLoad, and you're excpecting to do everything, than give a tab to all lines.

Comment: sorry i had missed out a small part of the code that prints it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code this will give you collective result in the form of dictionary.

```
from collections import OrderedDict

result = OrderedDict()  #creating a Ordered dictionary

#setting dictionary elements
result["Order_No"] = []
result["Deliver_Address"] = []
result["Bay_Collection"] = []
result["Stock"] = []

def WorkLoad(result):
    readWork=open("Todays_Work.txt","r")
    for line in readWork.readlines(): 
        WorkLine = line.split()
        result["Order_No"].append(WorkLine[0])
        result["Deliver_Address"],append(WorkLine[1])
        result["Bay_Collection"].append(WorkLine[2])
        result["Stock"].append(WorkLine[3])
    return result

data = Workload(result)  #calling the workload function
print(data)  #printing the data
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to print each line, you should add a print statement inside the loop. Or save them to a later use. Probably you want something like this:

```
Order_No = []
Delivery_Address = []
Bay_Collection = []
Stock = []
def WorkLoad():
    readWork=open("Todays_Work.txt","r")
    for line in readWork.readlines(): 
        WorkLine = line.split()
        Order_No.append(WorkLine[0])
        Deliver_Address.append(WorkLine[1])
        Bay_Collection.append(WorkLine[2])
        Stock.append(WorkLine[3])
        print(Order_No[-1], Deliver_Address[-1], Bay_Collection[-1], Stock[-1])
```

This prints each line during the loop and saves all the fields in the relative lists. I define the lists outside `WorkLoad` so they are available from other functions you may have. Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Indentation is off, and this is python3 so print function

Comment: I had tried this but for say in another function i tried to use Order_No it would then only return the last line's Order_No

Comment: ok, python 3. If you need to save all the lines to use them later, you need to save them in a list or another iterable.